# NGINX configuration example.com / www.example.com not working as expected

Tags: nginx, server

I am trying to set up a new website on a Ubuntu server running Nginx. I have the directory set up but I am getting some unexpected behavior.

This is my server block:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

root /var/www/website.org;
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name website.org www.website.org;
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

server_name website.org www.website.org;
root /var/www/website.org;

index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.org/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.org/privkey.pem;

ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:5m;
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.org/chain.pem; 
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

I have been through this over and over again. I checked my firewall and it seems to be set up fine. I have a couple of questions:

1. Based on my research, this server setup should be right. What am I missing?
2. I would like to handle both the "www" prefix and the no prefix version of my site with HTTPS. The behavior would be that the non-https would automatically redirect to the https. Therefore I have included the return statement in the port 80 server block. Do I need a separate SSL cert for the "www" subdomain? Should I have included that when I made the SSL cert originally? How would I do that?
3. Can I use wildcard syntax for the server block to catch the "www" subdomain? Would that be bad practice?

Comment: did you add the domain on your host file?

Comment: Did you create a symlink for the file?

Comment: @Kevin I did do the symlink

Comment: @Forbidden I did not do a domain on the host file. What is needed there?

Comment: What is the "unexpected behavior" you're referring to?

Comment: @Kevin at the moment the "www" prefix on the domain loads, but the "non-www' does not. Before it seemed like the "non-www" would load and the "www" would not. Seems a little erratic

Comment: 1. Look fine. 2. Yes, but Let's Encrypt can easily generate both domain names in a single certificate. 3. If these are the only server blocks in your configuration, they are already handling all requests received by the server irrespective of the `server_name` value, because they are also the [default servers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names).

Comment: Best way to test the configuration is with `curl -I`. Testing with the browser can appear erratic as the browser has a cache and will also be noticing the Strict-Transport-Security header.

Comment: When I try to use the CURL command on https://website.org I get "curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'website.org'
"

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding another server block to handle the https://www version of my website. It seemed that NGNIX did not want to allow the SSL for the WWW version and the non-WWW version in the same server block. Adding an additional server block to handle the SSL for the WWW version seems to solve the problem and allow the CURL request to hit all the options for getting to the website.